# How to cancel reading request with Jetty?

Tags: java, http, network-programming, jetty

I am using `Jetty 8` in blocking I/O mode. The servlet `doPost` reads the request content from the request `InputStream` (which is actually an instance of Jetty `HttpInput`).

What if a client sends a very large request and does it very slowly ? Obviously, it will take a lot of time to read the request. So, I would like to cancel the reading after a few seconds and send an error response to the client. How can I do that without much changes i.e. using `Jetty` with blocking I/O and without `continuation` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Jetty 9+ answer

Use `HttpServletResponse.sendError(-1)` to terminate the connection.

### Original Jetty 8 answer

Write a ServletFilter that does the detection of the slow request.
When you determine it is slow, ...

- Obtain a reference to the current connection via a call to [AbstractHttpConnection.getCurrentConnection()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractHttpConnection.html#getCurrentConnection%28%29)
- Get a reference to the EndPoint via [AbstractHttpConnection.getEndPoint()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/io/AbstractConnection.html#getEndPoint%28%29)
- Call [EndPoint.close()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/io/EndPoint.html#close%28%29)

Also, look into the [QoSFilter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/QoSFilter), it does a lot of this kind of stuff already.